# Custom dialog box: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I know this is a very common error - but being a C# newbie, I have found it extremely difficult to find the cause of the problem by looking at other posts as the problem is vague and can be applied to alot of scenarios. Hence why I am starting my own question. Hopefully by doing so I can understand more about the error, so I hope you guys don't mind.

It is my understanding that this error occurs when you try and reference a non-static object as if it were a static one. Am I thinking along the right lines?

My problem is such:
I am trying to create my own custom dialog box (rather than use the standard winforms one). So I have the following code:

```
public partial class Dialog : Form
{
    public Dialog(string header, string msg, bool closeable, int buttons)
    {
        if (!closeable)
            btnX.Hide();
        if (header != null || header != String.Empty)
            lblHeader.Text = header;
        if (msg != null || msg != String.Empty)
            lblMessage.Text = msg;
        InitializeComponent(); //Problem is here, this should be at the top.
    }

    private void btnX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

I am calling this `Dialog` class using the following line:

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog("HEADER", "HELLO", true, buttonChoice);
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

But I am getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on the line:

`lblHeader.Text = header;`
(And I assume I would also get it on the 'message' line too).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

**Update with answer**: Objects within the class should not be referenced before the `InitializeComponent()` function is called.

Comment: Side note - you can replace `if (header != null || header != String.Empty)` with `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))`

Comment: Thanks keyboard, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the `InitializeComponent()` call to the beginning of constructor.

`InitializeComponent` method contains all the initialization logic generated by the designer, including initialization of `btnX` and `lblHeader` controls that you are using.

Comment: Thank you - glad it was such a simple answer! At least now I know what the initializeComponent function does ;)      +1

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have the answer, but just a small addition:

> > It is my understanding that this error occurs when you try and reference a non-static object as if it were a static one. Am I thinking along the right lines?

Not really. This simply means that the object reference was not initialized yet due to the misplaced `InitializeComponent()`. If you'd try the same thing with static declared variables you'd get the same thing.

If you'd declare a static method and you try to access a member in the context of that static method, then you'd get the error

> > An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

In any event: +1 for Patko :)